# How do i import data from a table into another table(using arrays)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a drag and drop game that sorts through a football competition (group stages + eliminatory pyramid).

Here is the code for the dynamically generate group stages table+ the sorting 
function:

```
function drawTable() {
    var table_string = "<tr>";

    for (var k=1; k<=8; k++) {
        table_string+="<td><table id ='id"+k+"' class='floating'>";

        for ( var i=1; i<=4; i++ ) {
            table_string+="<tr>";
            table_string+="<td class='team_td' id='item"+i+""+k+"'></td>"
            table_string+="</tr>";
        }

        table_string+="</table></td>";
    }

    table_string+="</tr>"
    $("#groupStage").append(table_string);   
}

function randomizeTable() {
    var Teams = ["ALG", "ARG",  "AUS",  "BEL",  "BOS",  "BRA",  "CAM",  "CDI",
    "CHI",  "COL",  "CRC",  "CRO",  "ECU",  "ENG",  "FRA",  "GER",  "GHA",
    "GRE",  "HON",  "IRA",  "ITA",  "JPN",  "KOR",  "MEX",  "NED",  "NIG",   "POR", "RUS",  "SPN",  "SWI",  "URU",  "USA"];
    shuffleArray(Teams);
    var contor=0;

    for ( var i=1; i<=4; i++ ) {
        for ( var j=1; j<=8; j++ ) {
            $("#item"+i+""+j).append("<img src='Pics/"+Teams[contor]+".bmp'
/>");

            contor++;
        }
    }
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Now I can't figure out how to take the first 2 td's in each column to import them into another table(using the rules that A1 plays B2 and A2 plays B1 and so on).

Should it be something with a new array that maps the moves and takes the innerHtml?

Comment: can you show a working demo of what you have? maybe a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I cant put a jsfiddle because my code appends some pictures i have on my pc

Comment: don't worry about the pics. just the html, js etc.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Dstefanescu/oapgb7hd/ like this?

Answer (score 0):

something like this:-

```js
var groups = $('#groupStage').find('table.floating');
for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i += 2) {
  
  var aFirst = $(groups[i]).find('.team_td:eq(0)').get(0);
  var aSecond = $(groups[i]).find('.team_td:eq(1)').get(0);
  var bFirst = $(groups[i + 1]).find('.team_td:eq(0)').get(0);
  var bSecond = $(groups[i + 1]).find('.team_td:eq(1)').get(0);
  
  $('body').append('<div>' + aFirst.id + ' v ' + bSecond.id + '</div>');
  $('body').append('<div>' + bFirst.id + ' v ' + aSecond.id + '</div>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="groupStage">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Group A</th>
      <th>Group B</th>
      <th>Group C</th>
      <th>Group E</th>
      <th>Group F</th>
      <th>Group G</th>
      <th>Group H</th>
      <th>Group I</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table id="id1" class="floating">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item11">
                11
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item21">
                21
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item31">
                31
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item41">
                41
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table id="id2" class="floating">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item12">
                12
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item22">
                22
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item32">
                32
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item42">
                42
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table id="id3" class="floating">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item13">
                13
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item23">
                23
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item33">
                33
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item43">
                43
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table id="id4" class="floating">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item14">
                14
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item24">
                24
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item34">
                34
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item44">
                44
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table id="id5" class="floating">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item15">
                15
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item25">
                25
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item35">
                35
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item45">
                45
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table id="id6" class="floating">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item16">
                16
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item26">
                26
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item36">
                36
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item46">
                46
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table id="id7" class="floating">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item17">
                17
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item27">
                27
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item37">
                37
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item47">
                47
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table id="id8" class="floating">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item18">
                18
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item28">
                28
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item38">
                38
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="team_td" id="item48">
                48
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I will get back to you with an answer on monday! thanks for the interest